Duplicating routes in Laravel
I have a route in api.php:
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('api.login');

When I run command php artisan route:list, I see:
POST            api/login ........................................................................................ api.login › Api\LoginController@login

and
POST            api/messenger/login .............................................................................. api.login › Api\LoginController@login

I don't have route api/messenger/login anywhere in my code, how this possible?
I tried to clear all cache php artisan optimize:clear

Try grep messenger routes/* to see if it's hiding anywhere in there. Also, do you have any messaging packages installed in your composer?

I have group of routes named messenger but login not in this group. And I have another two routes not in messenger group and these routes also duplicated

Can you share your route file where you have defined messenger as a group of routes?

When I remove this string Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('api.login'); both routes is dissappear, it meens that this string create 2 same routes with defferent URIs

How to resolve this, add name prefix to API routes to make sure all API routes will not collide with web routes.
wrap all your API routes.
Route::name('api.')->group(function () {
   // All your API Routes
});

or even better
add it to the service provider app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php   in the boot function update to as below
Route::middleware('api')
  ->prefix('api')
  ->name('api.') //add this
  ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

more details can be found in the docs.

This is bad idea, api prefix should be in RouteServiceProvider

I agree,  you can add it to the resource provider
